# I can't persist Login statement in Android

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I set `Cookiemanager` with `CookiePolicy`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

    CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
    cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
    CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);

    setViews();
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    GetTimetable getTimetable = new GetTimetable();
    getTimetable.execute();
}

public class GetTimetable extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Timetable timetable = new Timetable();
        timetable.start();

        return null;
    }
}
```

And I send requests.

```
public void start() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(LOGIN_URL);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try {
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

            String urlParameters = URL_PARAMETERS;

            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            out.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        URL url = new URL(TARGET_URL);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try {
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while (in.readLine() != null) {
                response.append(in.readLine());
            }
            in.close();

            System.out.println(response.toString());
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I tested `start()` method in Eclipse with only Java and it worked.

Login by `POST` request, and get contents by `GET` request. but, in Android, it seems that it doesn't persist Login statement because POST request return headers successfully but Get request doesn't work at all.

I got stucked.

I really want to know how can I persist Login statement.

Thanks..!!

Comment: Can you return tokens when you login?

Comment: @FabioVenturiPastor in Eclipse, I can get it with 200 status code. but, in Android, I can't. It just return 500 error. I use same code. just add cookiePolicy when tested in Android.

Comment: 500 means something has gone wrong on the web site's server, are what message returns?

Comment: in Log message, I got java.io.FileNotFoundException at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206) I'm not sure that the problem is about permission or timeout or something